# insert array from input to MySQL PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I tried to insert multiple rows to PDO MySQL but it's didn't work
my code is below

```
<input type="text" name="firstname[]"> <input type="text" name="lastname[]">

function input_checker($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}

$firstname = input_checker($_POST["firstname"]);
$lastname = input_checker($_POST["lastname"]);

$rows = array($firstname, $lastname);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO memo(ID, firstname, lastname) 
VALUES (NULL, :firstname, :lastname)");
foreach($rows as $key => $value){
     $stmt->bindParam($key, $value);
  }
$stmt -> execute();
```

Comment: Please stop using `input_checker` (or an similarly named function). Just use the `htmlspecialchars` for outputting. Why don't you just pass `$rows` to the `execute` and use anonymous placeholders (`?`) in the query?

Comment: You are missing the `key`s in your array -> `$rows = array(':firstname'=>$firstname, ':lastname'=>$lastname);` See http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: @Sean please can you give me the full code

Comment: Why are you using firstname[], that square brackets at the end as you have only two input one for firstname and second one for last name.
Could you post your complete HTML code?

Answer (score 3):

`$rows` is not an associative array, so there's no `:firstname` and `:lastname` keys in it. Also, `bindParam()` binds to references, so using the same `$value` variable each time through the loop will bind both parameters to the last value from the loop.

You don't need the array in the first place. Just bind each parameter separately.

But `$_POST['firstname']` and `$_POST['lastname']` are arrays, so you need to loop through them.

```
$firstname = $lastname = null;
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO memo(ID, firstname, lastname) 
    VALUES (NULL, :firstname, :lastname)");
$stmt->bindParam(":firstname", $firstname);
$stmt->bindParam(":lastname", $lastname);
foreach ($_POST['firstname'] as $i => $firstname) {
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'][$i];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Try initializing the variables at the beginning, as I've added to my code.

Answer (score 1):

You are binding with the array index as the key (which are numeric in the version you are using), but you are using names for the parameters.

There is no need to use an array anyway as it is shorter to bind each parameter at a time...

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO memo(ID, firstname, lastname) 
            VALUES (NULL, :firstname, :lastname)");
$stmt->bindParam(":firstname", $firstname);
$stmt->bindParam(":lastname", $lastname);
$stmt -> execute();
```